# How get telegram channel info by username?

Tags: telegram, tdlib

I have a channel name, like `@name`. How i can gen info about this channel? Tdlib api have methods for this, but they work with channel id. 
Methods `joinChatByInviteLink` and `checkChatInviteLink` needs link with hash not channel username. How i can programmaticaly create this hash by username? Or any other variant get channel id?

Answer (score 0):

This method solve my problem with search https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1search_public_chat.html